# How get raw SQL from sequelize migraions

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a bunch of Sequilize migration files. All looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    up: //up migration
    down: //down migration,
};
```

Is there a programmatically way to get SQL queries from that files? It will be ok to use Node ecosystem. The only requirement do that automatically.

**Why do I want do this?**

I wan't to create SQL migrations from javascript files to put them into entrypoint of my Postgres base image for local development. And I don't want to put Node.js with Sequelize into my image which depends only on Postgres official base image from Docker Hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a database with the right schema, all you need is the schema. You can use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgdump.html) command to get the schema

```
pg_dump.exe -U username -d databasename -s schemaname> myschema.sql
```

You can now import this schema

```
psql -d database_name -h localhost -U postgres < myschema.sql
```

Comment: Will it work if there are a lot of extensions setups, sql functions, casts and other stuff? Does it included in schemas?

Comment: As long the database you are importing into has the same extensions, I do not see any reason why this would not work.

Comment: One single trouble left. To make pg_dump there is a requirement to have access to existing database, but my goal to made autonomous system for local development which can build all correct dependencies from zero (including DB) on local environment without access to real databases.

Comment: To get schema, you need db access. For local setup, you can use migrations which you already have

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking how to get this programatically but just exposing the raw SQL is valuable.  I was able to get the raw sql (sorting this out led me to this question) by adding the key `logging` to the `options` object.

This is my migration:

```
await queryInterface.addIndex(
    constants.EVENTS_TABLE_NAME,
    ['created_at'],
    { using: 'brin', concurrently: true, logging: console.log }
);
```

and the output from the migration:

```
== 20220311183756-create-brin-index-on-created-at: migrating =======
Executing (default): CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "events_created_at" ON "events" USING brin ("created_at")
== 20220311183756-create-brin-index-on-created-at: migrated (0.019s)
```

Here is an example from [their docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html):

```
await sequelize.query('SELECT 1', {
  // A function (or false) for logging your queries
  // Will get called for every SQL query that gets sent
  // to the server.
  logging: console.log,

  // If plain is true, then sequelize will only return the first
  // record of the result set. In case of false it will return all records.
  plain: false,

  // Set this to true if you don't have a model definition for your query.
  raw: false,

  // The type of query you are executing. The query type affects how results are formatted before they are passed back.
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```